# Create Transparent Windows in Haxe (Neko or Windows targets)

Tags: windows, flashdevelop, haxe, openfl, neko

Im trying to make a simple OSX-like dock application using Haxe 3.1.3. I cant seem to work out how to make the main application window transparent (no titlebars, borders etc), as well as ignoring mouse events except on the icons themselves. Ideally no taskbar item either, just a system tray item.

I believe Haxe Windows target uses SDL, and am pretty sure that SDL can support this kind of behaviour? Im not sure how Neko target is compiled, or handles this... Is there some flags I can set in the Haxe application.xml or something like that? Or is this just not possible with the Haxe Windows or Neko targets?

**EDIT**

I Discovered that the Waxe haxelib, which can be compiled with Neko, has a bunch of flags in the Window.hx file - https://github.com/nmehost/waxe/blob/cd9739e007ed10918166588faf2339d623b22fc4/wx/Window.hx

These include such options as FRAME_NO_TASKBAR and BORDER_DOUBLE, which both work when passed as arguments to the wx.Frame.create() function in the Simple.hx Waxe sample project.

It also includes the flag TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, but this appears to do nothing. No idea why the other flags are working, but the TRANSPARENT_WINDOW flag doesnt.

Answer (score -2):

In Openfl (it's openfl which uses sdl and a xml project), you can remove the window border with this in your application.xml:

```
<window borderless="true"/>
```

But I don't know a way to move the window without borders.

relevant discussion:
http://www.openfl.org/forums/#!/general:moving-borderless-windows

Comment: that creates a borderless window, not a transparent one.